# Obtener IDS con Drag&Drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este código que hace un drag&drop que saqué de la página de Javascript, funciona bien. Sólo tengo un problema, necesito el ID del div donde cayó.

Hice esto pero no funciona, me aparece undefinied el ID del grid.

```
function dragstart_handler(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
}

function dragover_handler(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop_handler(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
var idModulo = data;
var idGrid = $(data).closest('div').attr('id');
alert('El módulo es: '+idModulo+' y el grid es: '+idGrid);
}
```

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver la pregunta con meses?

Comment: Lo siento, ya lo corregí

Comment: @fredyfx Creo que Alberto se refiere a que ya corrigió el título

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo resolví

```
function createModule(module,grid)
{
    alert('El id del Módulo es: '+module+' y el id del Grid es: '+grid);
}

function dragstart_handler(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
}

function dragover_handler(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop_handler(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var newModule = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    var newGrid = ev.target.id; //ESTA LINEA CAPTURA EL ID DONDE CAYO
    createModule(newModule,newGrid);
}
```

Que sirva para el futuro

Comment: Hola @AlbertoSiurob , ¿podrías ser un poco más especifico con tu respuesta? explicar un poco el contexto, donde y cómo debería usar esas líneas de código? mira [answer]